# android studio java web service control every 45 seconds

Tags: java, android, service

I have to do an android service that communicates with a web service within 45 seconds. but i can't do it with business service or normal service. The system automatically shuts itself down after 10 minutes. I need help.

Comment: This is just too vague to proceed with, kindly be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class bildirim extends JobService {
    int Kul_Id = 0;
    String[] sto;
    int sayac = 0;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        final ipdatabase dbo = new ipdatabase(getBaseContext());
        sto = dbo.ipler(getBaseContext());
        database db = new database(bildirim.this);
        if (db.dbkontrol()) {
            List<String> cr = db.veriListele(2);
            if (!cr.isEmpty()) {
                Kul_Id = Integer.parseInt(cr.get(4));
            }
        }
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new arkaplan().execute("http://" + sto[0] + "/Services.asmx/bildirimal?Kul_ID=" + Kul_Id+"&durum=1");

            }
        },0,30000);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        JobSchedulerService.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext());
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    class arkaplan extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return jsonparser.getdata(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray listarray = obj.getJSONArray("list");
                JSONObject fistobj;
                for (int i = 0; i < listarray.length(); i++) {
                    fistobj = listarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int icon = R.drawable.redwhitefav;
                    NotificationManagerCompat notifiynm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(bildirim.this);
                    Notification notifiy = new NotificationCompat.Builder(bildirim.this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(icon)
                            .setContentTitle(fistobj.getString("Gork_Deger") + ": " + fistobj.getString("Gork_Mstad"))
                            .setContentText("Tanım: "+ fistobj.getString("Gork_Tanim")  + "\n"+ "Tarih: " + fistobj.getString("Gork_Baslangic"))
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                            .build();
                    notifiynm.notify(sayac, notifiy);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```